# Get closest date based on matching mutiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two tabs as below in Excel:

Table 1:

```
    Date      Vehicle Number      Planned Leave Time    Actual Leave Time
  8/7/2017        10001            8/7/17 4:59 AM
```

Table 2:

```
  Date   Vehicle Number   Actual Leave Time
8/7/2017    10001          8/7/17 4:29 AM
8/7/2017    10001          8/7/17 5:59 AM
8/7/2017    10001          8/6/17 3:05 PM
8/7/2017    10003          8/6/17 2:05 PM
```

I want to get the actual leave time from table 2 based on matching the same date, same vehicle number between table 1 and table 2;

Also, as you can see, there are multiple records for a same vehicle and same date in table 2, so I think I have to compare the time (8/7/17 4:59 AM) to all the time in table 2 that on 8/7/2017 and for vehicle 10001, to get the closest time, which has the minimum abs difference between my planned time and active time.

So can anyone please tell me what formula I should use in Excel in order to achieve my purpose?

Thanks so much
Pudge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned your data tables into `Tables` and used structured references, so it doesn't really matter where your tables are located. In addition, the formulas and references will automatically update if you add rows to either table. Also, you can rename the tables to something meaningful, if you like.

The formula is an **array** formula so must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces <kbd>{...}</kbd> around the formula:

```
=INDEX(Table2[Actual Leave Time], MATCH(MIN(ABS(([@Date]=Table2[Date])*([@[Vehicle Number]]=Table2[Vehicle Number])*Table2[Actual Leave Time]-[@[Planned Leave Time]])),ABS(([@Date]=Table2[Date])*([@[Vehicle Number]]=Table2[Vehicle Number])*Table2[Actual Leave Time]-[@[Planned Leave Time]]),0))
```

Comment: thanks, i did some google research before, it gave me some similar formula, however it did,t work for some reasons; but I copy your formula, it works fine, thank you